# Capistrano Wont Deploy Rails App With Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler, rbenv

I'm trying to set up my rails app onto a DigitalOcean Server with postgres, following [This Tutorial](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/18.04#vps). I am at the point where I am trying to deploy my app with capistrano, but when I run  `$cap production deploy`, it always fails with this error message:

```
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [1c7e325c]       )

 DEBUG [1c7e325c]       

 DEBUG [1c7e325c]       To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.

To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`

 DEBUG [1c7e325c]               from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'

 DEBUG [1c7e325c]               from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

 DEBUG [1c7e325c] Finished in 0.408 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

  INFO [5d18f10c] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/myapp/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet as deploy@1.2.3.4

 DEBUG [5d18f10c] Command: cd /home/deploy/myapp/releases/20190408225913 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.6.1" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/myapp/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet )

 DEBUG [969718b0]       /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe'

 DEBUG [969718b0]       : 

 DEBUG [969718b0]       Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /home/deploy/myapp/releases/20190408225913/Gemfile.lock.

 DEBUG [969718b0]        (

 DEBUG [969718b0]       Gem::GemNotFoundException

 DEBUG [969718b0]       )

 DEBUG [969718b0]       

 DEBUG [969718b0]       To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.

To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`

 DEBUG [969718b0]               from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'

 DEBUG [969718b0]               from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

This is my deploy file:

```
set :application, "myapp"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:user/myapp.git"
append :rbenv_map_bins, 'puma', 'pumactl'
# Deploy to the user's home directory
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}"


set :default_environment, {
    'PATH' => "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
}


append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

# Only keep the last 5 releases to save disk space
set :keep_releases, 5

# Optionally, you can symlink your database.yml and/or secrets.yml file from the shared directory during deploy
# This is useful if you don't want to use ENV variables
# append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'
```

I've already tried running `gem install bundler:2.0.1` and `gem install bundler` on both the deploy@myapp and my local computer. Any suggestions on how I can fix this problem, and fix the error that occurs when I try to deploy my app to production with capistrano rbenv?

***EDIT***
Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require "capistrano/rvm"
# require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
# require "capistrano/bundler"
# require "capistrano/rails/assets"
# require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
# require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.1'
```

Comment: Did you try to use capistrano-bundler gem?

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have bundler installed as the deploy user **after** switching into the proper `rbenv`:

```
rbenv global 2.6.1
bundler --version
```

If not install it: `gem install bundler:2.0.1`.

Otherwise make sure your `Capfile` has the rbenv label mentioned (see tutorial).

```
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.1'
```

Comment: When I switched to rbenv global 2.6.1 and checked the bundler version, it says bundler version 2.0.1. Also, check the post edit, I added the Capfile, which has the set:rbenv type and user, but when I use cap production deploy, it still throws the same error as before.

Comment: Hardcoding version in Capfile was to enforce the right rbenv is loaded for deployment. From your logs this seems the case (even before the Capfile tweak). But it seems that something went wrong installing the new version. Can you try `bundle update --bundler` as deploy user. Maybe bundler will autocorrect it. Usually double checking the error-logs and looking at the correctness of the paths helps with those type of issues.